# Why isn't there a Voided date property in DocuSignEnvelopeInformation object?

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign REST API 3.0 to integrate with my app.

After a DocuSign envelope is voided, if I invoke EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesAsync for the envelope, I get back an EnvelopesInformation object, which shows both a VoidedDateTime and a VoidedReason property. This is exactly what I need to update my database but all the documentation tells me I should implement 
a webhook to receive status updates instead of invoking the API, so I implemented the webhook.

However, when DocuSign invokes my webhook after I void an envelope, I get an DocuSignEnvelopeInformation object from DocuSign, which does not appear to have a VoidedDateTime or Voided property. There is a VoidedReason property, and there are properties for other status dates, such as Created and Sent. Why no Voided property?

What this means is that after the webhook is invoked (and updates my database with incomplete information), I still have to invoke the API to get the VoidedDateTime into my database. Did I just waste my time implementing the webhook? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly select `Envelope Voided Reason` checkbox in your Custom Connect configuration. Once this property is selected then you will be able to know the reason why this envelope was Voided.

[image: Voided Reason Reference snapshot]

Webhook is a notification system, where it will notify your System with some data/metadata about the envelope, and if that data does not seem sufficient for your requirement then you need to use API to pull the rest of the data. If Webhook is not available then you need to do a Polling mechanism using some scheduler to keep polling DocuSign after certain interval which does not seem to be a good design and not very scalable. So Webhook design helps your system to know when to call DocuSign platform.

Please note, it seems you are using SOAP API, but I would recommend to implement a new API integration with [DocuSign's Rest API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference) as it will have latest features which might be missing from SOAP API.

Comment: just updated my post to clarify that I am in fact using the REST API, not SOAP API. The Webhook is more than sufficient for all my other needs (get statuses, signed documents, etc.) except for getting the Voided date in cases where the envelope has been voided.Would you mind explaining where I can change this configuration?

Comment: VoidedDate is not returned by DS Connect message, but Voided Reason is returned. Updated my answer with snapshot how you could add Voided Reason in the Connect response.

Comment: thank you for including the screenshot of the configuration. The reason why I did not recognize it earlier is because I have not configured Connect in the Admin portal (as you have shown). I do it programmatically by using the `eventNotification` parameter when creating the new envelope. I have already turned on all the flags, but as we have both realized, Voided date is not one of the options. This is unfortunate!

Comment: If you are doing it programmatically then you need to set `includeEnvelopeVoidReason` value as `true` as explained [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#eventNotification)